# Linux from Scratch [LFS] developing environment?

Tags: linux, kernel, opensuse

I've recently delved into the LFS pdf in hopes of building my own OS and learning in the process. However, in the beginning of the book, they continue to speak of a development environment and how there's a LFS LiveCD and all this stuff.

My question is: Can I follow these instructions and still build my OS in an OpenSuse environment? I've checked that I have all the software needed. This may be an insanely obvious question but I'd rather do this well the first time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Having the LiveCD isn't a necessity. Rather I would recommend against building with the LiveCD, as it would be easier for you to build on your already installed distro, having access to helpful utilities such as your browser and IRC for all kind of help you might need during the install process.

So as long as you have all the necessary tools installed on your distro mentioned in the LFS book, you are good to go with your existing distro.

That said, it is good to have the LiveCD around. As you might need it if you ever run into any boot time problems, which are a norm if you are new to LFS.